# OpenCV, how to display a series of images without reinitializing a window

Tags: image, opencv, window

I'm currently working on a segmentation tools for medical images. It's basically a contour that evolves on each iteration of the algorithm.

What I want to do is display the contour on the image each 20 iterations. At the moment I'm doing that by creating a window, using the `cvDrawContour` function and using `imshow`. 
20 iterations later, I destroy the window and do these steps again.

Is there a way to create a window that won't be destroyed and where you can change the image that it displays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.  Just don't destroy your window every time.  Your image is stored in some `cv::Mat mat`, just use `cv::imshow("My Window", mat);` every time, no need to destroy it.

Comment: Thanks very much! It is a bit strange because I remember having already tried that but that it resulted in a grey image instead of what I expectet, that's why I was calling destroyWindow.
Anyway I've retried it and it works now. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1714518 - remember you need to call waitkey() at some point to make the window appear

Comment: @MartinBeckett - It is already in my code thanks. But I think it might be why it wasn't display properly previously, thanks for the tip

Comment: @user1714518 - it's a common source of bugs. = I don't need to read a key so I'l remove waitkey(). Why isn't my picture showing ?